# Programmatically add container-bound trigger to Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs

I am facing a use case in which a programmatically created document needs to be extended with a custom menu, also programmatically.

So my first intention was to create a container-bound trigger and add it programmatically. But when I had a look at the [TriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder) class, I realised that it only allows to create triggers for forms and spreadsheets, but not for docs.

Is there any way to add a trigger to a document in a programmatic way or to extend the menu in Google Docs besides having to add a script manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no current way to do this for a programmatically create a trigger against a existing document. Please log an enhancement in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

One workaround for now would be to make a copy of a "template" document that has the necessary scripts associated with it so that when you clone it the `onOpen` runs on that document and you get the necessary behavior.

Here is an [example document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AA96B9Tvb9QM7yF1fedA3vxqBnncjBKUazWglgRWgok/edit?usp=sharing) that when you make a copy you should get a new menu. You can make a copy programmatically using the `DriveApp` API with the `makeCopy` function that is [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy%28String%29)

Comment: Great, copying a template will work just perfectly, I didn't think of that... Thank you!

Comment: This is a really smart workaround. Would be really nice if we could just deploy container-bound scripts to all containers (new and existing) within a user's drive. *sigh*